# onedrive file picker aadsts70001 application is not supported for this api version

Tags: javascript, azure, onedrive, office365api

When trying to open a file with onedrive for business file picker I always get the same error:

aadsts70001 application is not supported for this api version

I have all the settings in azure for the application: clientId, redirectUri (http://localhost:2009) and all permissions for sharepoint online and graph api). I also changed manifest setting oauth2AllowImplicitFlow = true.

I'm using this example from microsoft. I just changed to my clientId:

https://github.com/rgregg/onedrive-filepicker-javascript

There's no way to make it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OneDrive File Picker JavaScript SDK v7.0 is using the App Model 2.0.

See [v2.0 Protocols - OAuth 2.0 & OpenID Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols/)

The app registers on Azure AD does not support this App Model.

To use the OneDrive picker, you need to register your application through the [Microsoft Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) and receive a Client Id.

When the login dialog popup, use your Azure AD account to sign-in.

Then you are able to use this JavaScript File Picker to access OneDrive for Business.